# Отступ UITableView у TabBar во вкладке "Еще"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

К TabBar Добавил 6 Контролеров, вкладка "Еще" создалась автоматически.

Как убрать этот отступ слева у таблицы? Из-за чего он вообще появился?
[image: скриншот]

Comment: Вы про линию или текст?

Comment: Про линию, ну и у текста большой отступ. В идеале хотел узнать как можно редактировать этот экран

Comment: и линия и отступ текста это правильное поведение. Что вы можете сделать - можно убрать линию и нарисовать свою любой длинны, по тексту можно установить `setIndentationLevel` и `setIndentationWidth`

Comment: @Max В созданном мною tableView отступ значительно меньше. Я не понимаю как мне редактировать этот экран созданный автоматически TabBar

Comment: Этот экран "называется" MoreNavigationController. Работать с ним можно, получив его, например, так:
let moreViewController = self.moreNavigationController.viewControllers[0]
А вот таблица на нем:
let moreTableView = moreViewController.view as! UITableView

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: Если это вам помогло, давайте тогда я комментарий преобразую в ответ, а вы его примете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При добавлении в TabBar > 5 штук контроллеров, в роль вступает специальный Navigation Controller под названием MoreNavigationController. Работать с ним можно, получив его, например, так:

```
let moreViewController = self.moreNavigationController.viewControllers[0]
```

А вот таблица на нем:

```
let moreTableView = moreViewController.view as! UITableView
```

Оперируя этим контроллером и таблицей, можно убрать отступы